# Ubercart theming

Tags: ubercart, theming

I have added the Ubercart module to drupal 7 and I am having difficulty with the current theme of the items Ubercart uses.  I can trace the stylesheets to the public_html/sites/default/files/css folder.  In this folder there are about 50 css stylesheets that look generated.

My issue is that the current colorschemes Ubercart is using on my site dont match.  I need to edit the stylesheets but can't find specifically where to do so.  The generated stylesheets with names like "css_LRLsfsdfgsg.css" do not do the trick.

Has anyone encountered this or know where I can properly style ubercart to work with my drupal site??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off the css aggregation at admin/config/development/performance and then clear your cache. Then with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) inspect the elements and then apply your own css overrides in your own theme or subtheme.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that. It was in the most obvious of places. Yet I woudln't have found it unless you told me to uncheck the aggregation for the CSS